# Best way to call external api in a web page

Tags: language-agnostic

I'm currently building a web page which require to call some system apis such as wifi apis.  I will build these apis in different modules in different platoform because my web site will run in multiple platoform and browsers. I can fulfill my task by using such as java applet or activex/.net component. But that will require installation of exteranal package. My questions is if there are any easy and portable way? My web programming language will be php.

Comment: Will these APIs be running in the client, or in the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you can't; you need to install something to call on the server, and have appropriate permissions.

These things are:

1. Silverlight
2. Flash maybe
3. ActiveX
4. Java

Depending on what you want, probably ActiveX is best. I can't speak for the others' ability to do what you need.

The web-programming language you use for this is meaningless.

Comment: Why do you say that ActiveX is best? It's banned in many companies.

Comment: Sorry, I was probably speaking accidentally from experience; these days ActiveX is probably not so great, due to browser support and general annoyingness.

Comment: I know all of these. But none of these are my choice.Thanks any way.